# How to run windows gvim from cygwin?

Tags: vim, cygwin

I am not able to run gvim from cygwin. When I try to open a new file with :

> gvim filename
>   gvim opens a file with 'No name' and displays error as :

```
Error detected while processing command line
E492: Not editor command: C:\cygwin\home\chandan\l
Press enter or type command to continue
```

More problematic is that I can't open existing file in the path

`>which gvim` shows `/usr/bin/gvim`

I have put `alias gvim=/cygdrive/c/Program\Files\(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe` still

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found this thread, I find the answer from [jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens) unacceptable. We're not asking to be told not to do it. I didn't like the other answers either there was always some quirk, like settings not used or an extra command line window popping up. I Did some digging and this works for me. No extra command line box for nothing and it uses my proper gvim settings.

```
alias gvim='HOME=/cygdrive/p/ cygstart /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe'
```

You simply need to alter the HOME to your own.  To find out what to put there run gvim from windows then put in ":echo $HOME" and hit enter in my case it shows P:\ so that translates to /cygdrive/p/

Also if your gvim.exe is in a different directory/version you'll need to adjust.

Now when I type 'gvim script.sh' at a cygwin command prompt it launches gvim with the file, all nice and neat!

***UPDATE***

I found a slightly better way to do this. Using the alias was tying up my session that I ran the gvim from, I wanted it to launch as a separate process, using "gvim  &" is inelegant as it lists job number when launching and displays a "done" line when completed.  I'm too fussy so I figured out how to get that all tidy by using a function.

Just add this to your .bash_functions file, it builds on the previous section regarding home directory and backslash use.

```
gvim() {
   ORIGHOME=$HOME
   HOME=/cygdrive/p/
   /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe $1 & disown
   HOME=$ORIGHOME
} 2>/dev/null
```

***UPDATE 2 for babun users!***

Ok since having wrestled with this originally I have ended up scrapping the original cygwin install in favor of babun which seems to be a less troublesome setup for those wanting linux functionality in windows without a full blown virtual.  Of course my gvim launch script broke, and I had to do the following in my .zshrc file (babun uses zsh, at first I resisted and switched it to bash but then relented as I figured they must have reason, and they did, I like it)

```
gvim() {
   OLD_HOME=$HOME
   OLD_VIMRUNTIME=$VIMRUNTIME
   export HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/gmitchell/
   export VIMRUNTIME="C:\Program Files (x86)\VIM\vim74"
   TARGET=$(cygpath -w $1)   
   (/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe $TARGET &)
   export HOME=$OLD_HOME
   export VIMRUNTIME=$OLD_VIMRUNTIME
}
```

*Note: the surrounding curved braces ( ) stops the job id from messing up your clean shell, and you no longer need the  "disown"

P.S. The only remaining annoyance with this now is that you cannot "exit" the babun shell until all gvim instances you've launched are closed.  Maybe someone can figure that own out.  I've tried.  When you type exit it just hangs there until you've exited all gvims.

Comment: Thank You for your fussiness!  This works just like I'd want, with one drawback:  HOME is left set the way gvim wants, not the way my cygwin shell wants.  Also, I think for C:\P, you'd want to use '/cygdrive/c/P'.

Comment: You are correct it would have been /cygdrive/c/P, but I messed up when I typed that in somehow, it was showing P:\ as my windows homedir gets set to a P drive.  I hadn't noticed that issue with cygwin vs gvim home settings, I just tried it and you are correct it leaves my cygwin shell with change $HOME, I will fix up my script to carry the original $HOME through the command.

Comment: @jspencer, just noticed you posted a fix, well done.  Thanks for being as fussy as me :)  I'm using your version...

Answer (score 9):

I wrote [cyg-wrapper.sh](https://github.com/LucHermitte/Bash-scripts#cyg-wrappersh) for this sole purpose.

It supports:

- symbolic links
- options that must not be interpreted as pathnames (see `-c` with gvim, or any flags starting with a minus sign).

In other words, it enables us to type:

```
  gvim /etc/profile -c /PS1 -c "echo 'correctly opened'"
# or even:
  cd ~/tmp ; ln -s ~/bin/cyg-wrapper.sh 
  gvim -d http://hermitte.free.fr/cygwin/cyg-wrapper.sh cyg-wrapper.sh

  explorer -e
  explorer "$vim"
  explorer http://hermitte.free.fr/
```

Note: I use the following function in my .profile to run gvim with cyg-wrapper.sh

```
gvim() {
    opt=''
    if [ `expr "$*" : '.*tex\>'` -gt 0 ] ; then
    opt='--servername LATEX '
    fi
    cyg-wrapper.sh "C:/Progra~1/Edition/vim/vim73/gvim.exe" --binary-opt=-c,--cmd,-T,-t,--servername,--remote-send,--remote-expr --cyg-verbose --fork=2 $opt "$@"
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Currently (Sept 26 2014, using Vim 7.4), Windows gVim uses `C:\Windows\gvim.bat` to launch gVim from the command line. Replacing the `gvim.exe` path in the `gvim()` function with this script allows launching gvim without changing the path to match the current Vim version (which may actually be in `Progra~2`); however, it appears to also open a superfluous `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: I can now type "gvim /tmp/myfile.txt" and not see "New Directory".  For two years I've used c:\temp because I wanted vim.org gvim (mostly for Explorer integration).  This is so much better.

Answer (score 8):

Do yourself a favor, don't attempt to run a windows gvim from cygwin. The set of environment variables is likely completely different, and the pain of backslash directory separators, blanks in filenames, inability to understand /cygwin paths makes this an exercise in futility.

Then, what? Install the cygwin version of gvim and forget about all these problems.

Comment: Thanks Jens. After >startxwin I am able to open files with gvim in new window. But .gvimrc file which is in my home directory is not being recognised. Please let know how to.

Comment: Likely you and gvim disagree which directory your home directory is. Does `gvim -u .gvimrc` work?

Comment: yes gvim -u .gvimrc.vim filename opens a file with filename backgroud dark. But now after setting alias as given in Luc's page is working with syntax plugins that I installed earlier so I prefer that.

Comment: I use Windows gVim for my typical editing needs; the only reason I even use the Cygwin gVim is for quick access to an editor from within a Cygwin shell (which I use for easy access to friendly *NIX command-line utilities). But I've found that using two different versions of Vim on one machine is a nightmare; even though I managed to get them both to use the same `vimrc` file, I still need to launch XWin just to get an editor up, and there are various other strange issues I keep running into. So don't flatly dismiss the idea of just using the native version; for some of us this is just painful.

Comment: @Kyle Strand, just add xinit to Windows startup. It sits there occupying less than 2MB, and I get a nice gvim matching my console vim any time I want. Mind elaborating on other issues? scrooloose vimrc has shown no problems for me...

Comment: @Gordon I suppose I could do that, in which case I'd probably just use the Cygwin vim all the time--though I'm not sure how to make launching it as easy as launching the native gVim (e.g. via the right-click context menu), or whether that's possible; in any case I'd need to spend even more time than I've already spent trying to get it to work as nicely as I'd like. In any case, my main other issue is the font; perhaps someone with more familiarity of how fonts work in Cygwin/XWin could quickly and easily get an acceptable font, but I just couldn't justify spending the time.

Comment: In short, it's not so much a matter of "the Cygwin solution simply won't work because <whatever>" as "although the Cygwin solution might be feasible, the cyg-wrapper solution is quick and easy and so far seems to work exactly as I want it to".

Answer (score 4):

Here is all you need to do:

```
alias gvim="run.exe /cygdrive/c/Programming/Tools/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe"
```

Works also with Notepad++, like so:

```
alias np="run.exe /cygdrive/c/Programming/Tools/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but for me it doesn't load the _vimrc in my windows home directory properly. It doesn't load the .vimrc in my cygwin home directory either.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem
because of the $SHELL var

so, I simple do like this

`alias gvim='cmd /c "set SHELL=cmd & start gvim"'`

It works for me, may be this will be help you too.

and maybe you want use the same alias for vim.

Answer (score 2):

I put the following function in my `.bashrc`:

```
function gvim
{
    GVIM_CMD=/cygdrive/c/path/to/gVimPortable.exe
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]
    then
      $GVIM_CMD
    else
      $GVIM_CMD `cygpath -w $1`
    fi
}
```

This allows me to launch gVim from anywhere.

It works fine for files with spaces, too...

Comment: It's worth noting that the only way I could get this to work was with the short form windows path (/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Vim/vim74 instead of /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74). You can use cygpath to get the correct path for your system: $ cygpath -d /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/

Answer (score 1):

This is a take off on [low351](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3310901/low351)'s answer.  I was unhappy with leaving HOME changed in the cygwin terminal, since I use that locally for a cygwin HOME, not my windows home.  But gvim is all setup using Windows HOME.  I added this to my .zshrc:

```
# run windows gvim from command line
gvim() {
   local OLD_HOME=$HOME
   HOME=/cygdrive/c/Users/jason/
   local TARGET=$(cygpath -w $1)
   /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe $TARGET & disown
   HOME=$OLD_HOME
} 2>/dev/null
```

really, just storing and restoring HOME.  Being local, OLD_HOME goes away when the function returns, so it doesn't pollute the environment.  If you're editing a cygwin file, running it through cygpath -w will make it a file path that windows gvim understands.  It also lets you use window paths (e.g. `C:/tmp/foo.txt`) but w/ unix '/' separators, so you can dispense with `/cygdrive/c`.  I believe this is all compatible w/ bash.  This gives the following output:

```
> gvim
[2] 5060
>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the main problem is the HOME and VIM variables which are appropriate to the cygwin environment get exported when running Windows gvim, causing problems because Windows gvim knows nothing of cygwin. This fixes it:

```
alias gvim='env -u HOME -u VIM /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe'
```

I have Windows gvim set as the default application (in Windows) for many filetypes, so Windows gvim frequently gets opened via the `open` alias. This fixes that use case:

```
alias open='env -u HOME -u VIM cygstart'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed `gvim.bat` which comes with the standard Win32 vim installation to `gvim` and put it into /usr/bin.

I am also sharing settings beetween Win32 GVim and Cygwin VIM referring to this article:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Synchronize_configuration_to_many_computers

This way i can have both Vim and Win32 Gvim running with the same plugins and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've tried all of these and had issues I'll show what I'm using. I wrote it in ruby and it handles everything I throw at it (files, directories, or nothing) without any errors/popups/etc.

I saved it as `gvim` in ~/Dropbox/bin/cygwin/ (which is in my PATH)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

args=''
filepath=''
arg=ARGV[0]

if arg
    if File.exist? arg
        if File.file? arg
            args+="--remote-tab-silent "
        end
        filepath=`cygpath -w '#{arg}'`.strip
        filepath="'#{filepath}'"
    end
else
end


exe="'/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/vim/vim73/gvim.exe' #{args} #{filepath}"
spawn exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I use for `~/bin/gvim`. It runs it as if I called `gvim FOO` from the "Run" dialog (thanks to the batch file being invoked by `explorer.exe`). Can't play too nicely with the command line, but a self-deleting batch file comes to the rescue.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEMPFILE_NAME=gvim-`date +%s`-${RANDOM}.bat
TEMPFILE=$TMP/$TEMPFILE_NAME
TEMPFILE_W=`cygpath --windows --absolute --long-name "$TEMPFILE"`
TARGET=

if [ "$1" = "" ] ; then
  TARGET=`cygpath --windows --absolute --long-name "."`
else
  TARGET=`cygpath --windows --absolute --long-name "$@" | tr '\n' ' '`
fi

WIN_GVIM=`where gvim.exe | tr -d '\r\n'`
WIN_GVIM=`cygpath "$WIN_GVIM" --windows --absolute --long-name`

unix2dos > $TEMPFILE  << EOF
start "gvim" "$WIN_GVIM" $TARGET
DEL %~f0
EOF
chmod +x $TEMPFILE

explorer.exe "$TEMPFILE_W"
```

Special thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282423/129686) for the `explorer.exe` technique.