# How to launch a new cmd window with the correct path from Cygwin?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, cygwin

When I start cmd.exe from start menu, I get the registered (in registry) PATH variable, in a new window.

I want to have exactly the same effect from my cygwin+mintty, and try the followings:

Firstly I try:

```
bash$  cmd
```

This gives me a cmd shell, right inside mintty.  But I want it to be in a fresh new window.  emm...  Perhaps I can try:

```
bash$  cmd /c start cmd
```

It nicely gives me a cmd shell in a new window.  Good.  However, the PATH inside that command shell is not the same as a fresh new one.

```
C:\>path
PATH=C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapa
th;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\W
indowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\opencv\myrelease\bin;C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Perfo
rmance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\cygwin64\
lib\lapack;D:\home\robin_hsu\bin

C:\>
```

You can see those paths with `cygwin64` are not wanted.  So, what can I do to get a new fresh cmd window, with correct PATH?

Note: I believe the problem is due to PATH is inheritable, from `bash` to `cmd`.

Perhaps someone can give me some hint to get the registered PATH of windows system under cygwin's bash.   If that is possible, I can first change the PATH to the desired one, and then call `cmd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is basically a duplicate question to [Start new cmd.exe and NOT inherit environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261156/start-new-cmd-exe-and-not-inherit-environment).  However, that question doesn't ask to open a new window, and at least for me the answers there didn't give me a correct path.  The following command gives both (for me, on XP).

`cygstart "$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "$WINDIR\system32\cmd.exe"`

The only issue is that it also brings up dialog boxes 'File Download - Security Warning' AND 'Windows Explorer - Security Warning'.  [This link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e3008c75-48b4-4a6c-bc14-5a20ce72cd7f/disable-open-file-security-warning) shows how you can avoid this in general, but I'm not sure if it's possible to remove the warnings for just one specific file.  There are also a couple of answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/38610/open-file-security-warning-dialog-box) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/324954/how-can-i-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-when-i-want-to-run-downloaded) on superuser.com about disabling the warnings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that PATH is inherited from cygwin's bash shell to cmd.  `$USERPROFILE` is just the home folder.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I want.  In my Win7, it does not bring up any dialog box.  In fact, `explorer "$WINDIR\system32\cmd.exe"` also works, without `cygstart`