# Start cmd.exe from cygwin shell with original Windows environment variables?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, cygwin

I cannot use vcvarsall.bat from cygwin because cygwin overwrites environment variables (like PATH) and then the environment in cmd.exe, which is inherited from the cygwin BASH environment, finds the wrong cmake.exe.

Is there any pre-defined way to do this? Maybe without having to resort to opening a new shell window? Currently, I'm rewriting and stripping the entire PATH string. But now I have another issue: TEMP points to the wrong directory. I could just change that manually, but I really want it to adhere to original Windows behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261156/start-new-cmd-exe-and-not-inherit-environment

Comment: What is `vcvarsall.bat` ? It is not part of Cygwin. Why you can not run it from CMD without passing through Cygwin ?